# Bluetooth on some android devices work slowly while listening to music via TWS headphones

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a Samsung S8 with Android 9.
When I'm using TWS headphones to listen to music, the phone's Bluetooth scanning performance significantly reduced (as well as connecting performance). This issue also happens on several different other models of mobile, like Huawei or Samsung A51.

Is there any good explanation for this?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation would probably be that you have only one Bluetooth Adapter built into your phone. If you are using it 50% of the time to stream music you only have 50% left to do the other things in between

Comment: The strange point is this issue only occurs with some mobile phone models, for example: Samsung s8. And I got no problem with Xiaomi one.
Actually, I think bluetooth adapter on Samsung is stronger than Xiaomi, or at least equal.

Comment: Another thing to check would be some strange energy saving features, different vendors use different techniques